# Google analytics app + web having issue with Android App

Tags: android, google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics

I am working on Google Analytics App + Web into an Android app, and I am facing an issue that Google Analytics doesn't show any screen view and Events for the Android app.

I notice one thing that, new Google Analytics App + Web property changes their propertyID from UA-xxxxxx-x to 2xxxxxxx-xx.

So my concern is what we set here? Because now we didn't get Id starting with UA-xxxxxx-x now. (This is happened after making Google Analytics App + web)

```java
<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-xxxxxxxx-x</string>
```

Sending event using mTracker:

```java
AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
Tracker mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
mTracker.setScreenName("ScreenActivityName");
mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
```

I already created Project with Firebase and link with Google Analytics from the Integration tab in the Firebase console, but still not able to track event in GA. Even already created **Data Stream** from Admin Part in GA.

May I know what was the missing part?

Comment: The google analytics website doesnt show screen views for that you need to use firebase analytics.

Comment: I already used Firebase Analytics for event tracking, but one of my older apps uploaded on the play store working fine before few months, when I change Analytics App + Web, it is working stopped.